# How to put value to blank array inside foreach loop php

Tags: php, arrays

I am using query in foreach loop (according to userType) and after query in foreach loop i am getting
following result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [bookingId] => 1
            [userId] => 102
            [status] => paid
        }
    [0] => Array
        (
            [bookingId] => 3
            [userId] => 102
            [status] => paid
        }       
    [0] => Array
        (
            [bookingId] => 5
            [userId] => 102
            [status] => paid
        }
...     
        
}
```

Now i want all result outside foreach loop so i tried with following code but not working,showing me single record istead of multiple

I tried with following code but not working for me

```
$record=array();
    foreach ($result as $key => $row)
    {
            $query= // mysql query
            $rows = $query->result_array();
            $record['bookingId']=$rows['0']['bookingId'];
            $record['userId']=$rows['0']['userId'];
            $record['status']=$rows['0']['status'];
    }
echo "<pre>";print_R($record);
```

Comment: One recommendation is that you should try and reduce the SQL queries so that you don't execute a query inside the loop.

Comment: If you just say **not working**, we cannot understand much. Are you getting any error with your approach? If so, please post that error. Otherwise, mention the expected output and the output which you are getting with your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you rewrite the value in the array every time?

```
$record = array();
foreach ($result as $key => $row) {
    $query = // mysql query
    $rows = $query->result_array();
    $record[] = [
        'bookingId' => $rows['0']['bookingId'],
        'userId' => $rows['0']['userId'],
        'status' => $rows['0']['status'],
    ];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_R($record);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use it something like this.

```
$record = array();

foreach ($result as $key => $row)
{
      $query = // mysql query
      $rows = $query->result_array();
      $record[]['bookingId'] = $rows['0']['bookingId'];
      $record[]['userId'] = $rows['0']['userId'];
      $record[]['status'] = $rows['0']['status'];
}

echo "<pre>";print_R($record);
```

Basically, you're missing updating the index of the array.